# Capitalization of certain titles

Tags: ortografía

I've read that titles aren't capitalized. Does this also apply when the title precedes the name, e.g. Superintendent Johnson or President Trump? Would this be "el superintendente Johnson" "el presidente Trump"?

Answer (score 4):

No, in Spanish you don't use capitals in these cases.

You can find the whole set of rules regarding capitalization in Spanish in  [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=may%C3%BAsculas.).

There, in the section on when **not** to capitalize words, subsection 6.9 states:

> 6.9. Los títulos, cargos y nombres de dignidad como rey, papa, duque, presidente, ministro, etc., se escriben con minúscula cuando aparecen acompañados del nombre propio de la persona que los posee, o del lugar o ámbito al que corresponden (el rey Felipe IV, el papa Juan Pablo II, el presidente de Nicaragua, el ministro de Trabajo).